# Specify which template/layout to use based on URI segment

Tags: templating, routes, routing

I have 3 level structure for my entries with separate template for each level.

`/artists/artist-name/` uses `artists/_types/artists.html` template

`/artists/artist-name/section-name/` uses `artists/_types/section.html` template

`/artists/artist-name/section-name/project-name/` uses `artists/_types/project.html` template

What I need to do is to specify additional layout for level 3 entry so depending on URI I can display one or another.

This is the additional URI I want to use:
`/artists/artist-name/section-name/project-name/thumb` and I want to load the `artists/_types/thumb.html` template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure about what you're asking, but you might want to look in to craft.request:
 https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.request

In your structure template, you can check your URL segments, and use twig include to load the desired template, based on those segments.

Another related feature is dynamic routing:
https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes

You could use this to route a URL to a different template.

Comment: I tried to get crafty.request to work but without any luck. Ended up setting up a route. Not sure if this is really the proper way to do it but I got it to work.

`artists/(slug)/(slug)/(slug)/thumb` loads `artists/_types/thumb.html` template